# Groovy:(Templated) method from class does not override method from its superclass or interfaces but is annotated with @Override.*

Tags: templates, groovy

I don't see this question answered on here, in this exact edition....

...but, for some reason, in Groovy, when I override a templated method from a base class, with different parameter name, it fails.

### My base class

I have this `BaseSheetHandler` that is an abstract class of type `T`. It is defined to be:

```
public abstract class BaseSheetHandler<T> implements RandomRecordGenerator<T> {
    protected Sheet sheet;
    protected List<T> usedRecords;

    protected BaseSheetHandler(Closure<Sheet> onGetSheet) {
        onGetSheet.setResolveStrategy(Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST);
        onGetSheet.setDelegate(this);
        this.sheet = onGetSheet(this.getSheetName());
        this.init();
    }

    protected void init() {
        this.usedRecords = [];
        SMDSpreadsheetUtils.ExtractDataFromSheet(this.sheet,
                { int rowNum -> this.extractRecordFromSheet(rowNum) });
    }

    public void handle(T record) {
        this.usedRecords.push(record);
    }

    public List<T> getUsedRecords() {
        return usedRecords;
    }
    
    protected void writeRecordsToSheet(Closure onDone) {
        this.usedRecords
            .forEach({ T record ->
                // for some odd reason, in here, this refers to this Closure, nothing else
                fillInRow(getRow(record),
                    record);
            });
        onDone(this.sheet);
    }
    
    protected abstract Row getRow(T record); // <- this is the method we're trying to override/implement

    protected abstract String getSheetName();

    protected abstract void setupFirstRow(Row row);

    protected abstract void extractRecordFromSheet(int rowNum);

    protected abstract void fillInRow(Row row, T record);
}
```

We are introducing an abstract templated method `getRow()` on this class. We will implement it on derived classes.

### My derived class

One of my already-existing derived classes, `BasePracticeProfileSheetHandler`, implements this method with no issue:

```
@InheritConstructors
public abstract class BasePracticeProfileSheetHandler extends BaseSheetHandler<PracticeProfile> {
    protected Map<String, String> dict;

    @Override
    protected Row getRow(PracticeProfile record) {
        return SMDSpreadsheetUtils.FindRowWithKey(sheet, record.getPracticeName());
    }
}
```

However, when it comes to introducing another templated base class, we face issue:

```
@InheritConstructors
public abstract class ChildModelSheetHandler<ChildModel extends BaseModel> extends BaseSheetHandler<ChildModel> {
    Map<Long, ChildModel> childModelDict = [:];

    @Override 
    protected Row getRow(ChildModel record) {
        return SMDSpreadsheetUtils.FindRowWithKey(sheet, record.getId());
    }

}
```

Keep in mind, `BaseModel` is a concrete class, that has been imported.

### The error message

Is like:

```
Groovy:Method 'getRow' from class 'com.signaturemd.utils.recordHandler.rateIncrease.ChildModelSheetHandler' does not override method from its superclass or interfaces but is annotated with @Override.
```

However, if I change the type from a generic subclass of `BaseModel` to just `T` again, the error goes away!

What is going on here, and what can I do about it?

### Runtime environment

I am coding in Katalon Studio v8.5.1, which uses Groovy v3.9.0 . I am also on Java 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the code below will fail with exactly same message as you have in question

```
public abstract class BaseSheetHandler<T>{
    protected abstract String getRow(T record);
    protected abstract String other();
}

public abstract class ChildModelSheetHandler<HashMap extends Map> extends BaseSheetHandler<HashMap> {
    @Override 
    protected String getRow(HashMap record) {
        return "record=${record}";
    }
}

class A extends ChildModelSheetHandler<Map>{
    @Override 
    protected String other() {
        return "other()";
    }
}

def a=new A()
```

> Method 'getRow' from class 'ChildModelSheetHandler' does not override method from its superclass or interfaces but is annotated with @Override.
> at line: 7, column: 5

However if you change `HashMap` to something abstract => `T`

the code will compile without any issue...

```
public abstract class ChildModelSheetHandler<T extends Map> extends BaseSheetHandler<T> {
    @Override 
    protected String getRow(T record) {
        return "record=${record}";
    }
}
```

The problem that `HashMap` in `<HashMap extends Map>` is an abstract name.

When in `protected String getRow(HashMap record) {...}` HashMap is a real class name.

---

So, I bet that `ChildModel` in your code is a name of a real class/interface.

---

another option to make this code working - change `<HashMap extends Map>` to `<HashMap>`

```
public abstract class ChildModelSheetHandler<HashMap> extends BaseSheetHandler<HashMap> {
    @Override 
    protected String getRow(HashMap record) {
        return "record=${record}";
    }
}
```

Comment: When I investigate that, by creating a `ChildModel`, I see an error on that line. 

Hence, in this class `ChildModel` is not a real class/interface in my code base.

Comment: I see...I should keep the name the same... `T`, but I can be like `T extends BaseModel`